# Accessing hash values inside an array and moving them to a new array or hash using a loop

Tags: ruby, arrays, methods, hash

So I am using Ruby and trying to program a cash register that has item sku/types/prices and am having trouble figuring out the best way to query a hash inside of an array to access these values and add them to an order, say if 5 small and 3 large were ordered. Can anyone please help suggest how to go about this? I can write the display/menu interface I just don't know the best/easiest way to search for that data if someone orders it and then move those values into another hash or array so that it will comprise that customer's whole order which could then eventually all be summed up to get the totals from all the orders.

```
@sku_menu = [{Type => Small, SKU => 11, Price =>5.00},
            {Type => Medium, SKU 22 =>, Price => 7.50},
            {Type => Large, SKU => 33, Price => 9.75}]
```

\n

Comment: It'd help if you posted valid hash definition. Is this the farthest you got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make the keys of your hash symbols, not constants. Same for the type values:

```
@sku_menu = [
  { type: :small,  :sku => 11, price: 5.00 },
  { type: :medium, :sku => 22, price: 7.50 },
  { type: :large,  :sku => 33, price: 9.75 },
]
```

Next, we select values that we want:

```
# Gives an array of just the 'large' items
larges = @sku_menu.select{ |hash| hash[:type]==:large }

# Gives just the hash with the desired SKU
sku22 = @sku_menu.find{ |hash| hash[:sku]==22 }

# Gives an array of hashes
expensive = @sku_menu.select{ |hash| hash[:price] > 7 }

# Gives an array of hashes with the specified SKUs
selected = @sku_menu.select{ |hash| [11,22].include?( hash[:sku] )  }
```

Now, if you want to make it easier to find an item by SKU, try making it a Hash instead of an Array:

```
@sku_menu = {
  11 => { type: :small,  :sku => 11, price: 5.00 },
  22 => { type: :medium, :sku => 22, price: 7.50 },
  33 => { type: :large,  :sku => 33, price: 9.75 },
}

sku11 = @sku_menu[11]
```

And with this you can still `select` desired items (but in a slightly different syntax):

```
# Gives an array of just the 'large' items
larges = @sku_menu.values.select{ |hash| hash[:type]==:large }

# …alternatively
larges = @sku_menu.select{ |sku,hash| hash[:type]==:large }.values
```